# Clipping Imagery Services Layers from ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.2, imagery, clip, arcgis-online

The new Landscape layers such as the various Soil type imagery services look like a great resource. Does anyone know if it possible to clip out small areas of the Landscape imagery service since I only need the soil data on a small area.  Clipping it will look much cleaner if I can clip to the feature class of my area of interest. When trying to run the Clip tool in ArcMap 10.2, I can't get the imagery service to show as an option to clip.

Answer (score 3):

You can run the tool, "Make Image Service Layer", which will create a temporary file. Then you can "clip" or "extract by mask" the data that you need.

Answer (score 2):

There are many options for graphically **[Clipping the Data Frame](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s90000000q000000)** so if you do not want to create a new dataset this may meet your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer PolyGeo.  Unfortunately this doesn't help since I do need a new dataset of the clipped imagery service.

Answer (score 1):

Those WMS services cannot be clipped out other than a File>Export Map option within ArcMap (which only gives you a raster graphic).  If the service was a WFS you could use the [WFS to Feature clas](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00120000000q000000)s tool.  You may clip out polygon shapefile data from NRCS/USDA site at:

http://websoilsurvey.sc.egov.usda.gov/App/WebSoilSurvey.aspx

Comment: It's kind of looking like this is not possible unfortunately.

Comment: @wilbev, What is not possible, clipping WMS or downloading data from NRCS/USDA site?

Comment: Clipping the Esri Imagery service.  Downloading from the NRCS site would end up being much too many steps for my situation.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the exact solution but may help you on your journeys.

Take a look at the Downloading data from an image service article in the help menu of ArcGIS 10.2. Geodata>data types>rasters and images>displaying raster data>[Downloading data from an image service](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009t00000247000000).

---

it outlines that downloading capability is controlled by the admin of the service. Try downloading the data, if possible, and clipping using the raster clip tool in Arctoolbox>Data management tools> raster> raster processing> Clip.

Comment: Thanks MDHAld for the answer.  I tried what you suggested and these Landscape Imagery services don't seem to allow you to download them in anyway. They don't have any of the options available that is described in the help menu.  I imagine they have this shut off.  Maybe this just isn't possible as Esri has it too locked down.  This greatly reduces their usefulness.